# Equivalent of Password Char in GTK#

Tags: c#, linux, gtk, gtk#

I am in the middle of porting a WinForms app to GTK#.  In the WinForms version, I have a textbox with a password char of "*", but unfortunately, I can not seem to replicate this in GTK#.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: The C interface of Gtk for `GtkEntry` has `gtk_entry_set_visibility`; you need to use the `GTK#` equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

For whoever is still looking for this answer, here it is.

For any given entry, if you turn the member "visibility" to "false" you will get hidden characters such as:

So

```
foo.Visibility = false;
```

[image]